# Google spreadsheet: security error from flex

Tags: apache-flex, security

I have an app that uses a google spreadsheet to populate a menu and some related pages. Works great in debug but gives the "security error" when released.

It seems like some google services (eg picasa) permit flex apps to access them. Is google docs not open this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the API URL you are checking?  Does that URL have a CrossDomain.xml file?  If not; then you can't access it directly from a Flex (or Flash Player) app.  You'll have to use a Proxy of sorts.

Most people implement Proxy's on the server side.  Basically, your Flex app will call the proxy and send the appropriate data.  The proxy will then call the API (in this case Google Docs), get the results of that call, and then return the results to the Flex app.

Doing a quick search, I found this [page](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/developers_guide.html#ListingSpreadsheets).  Are you trying to access the spreadsheets.google.com URL?  If so, check out it's [crossdomain.xml](https://spreadsheets.google.com/crossdomain.xml) file.  It appears to prevent all access.

Comment: Yeah I saw the crossdomain file. I was hoping there was a workaround for it.

Comment: It seems odd to prevent flex directly but permit such an easy alternative. I wonder what the rationale is.

Comment: Some some research into cross site scripting.  Here is one link:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

Comment: No worries. I faked it with 5-10 lines of php.